# twig template - "if" codition as function parameter

Tags: twig

i am learning Twig:

```
{{ my_custom_func( {% if foo|default( 'bar' ) is not defined %}, {size: 50} ) }}
```

*first function parameter will be variable foo, if foo si not defined, first parameter will be string 'bar' (am i right with condition syntax?)*

but it not works

how can i place twig condition in this place (function parameter)?

thanks for help

Answer (score 1):

Use the the ternary operator:

```
{{ my_custom_func( foo is defined ? foo : 'bar' ) }}
```

or use [set](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/tags/set.html)

```
{% if foo is not defined %}
  {% set foo = 'bar' %}
{% endif %}
{{ my_custom_func( foo ) }}
```